# Time machine not recognizing sparsebundle

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, time-machine, sparsebundle

I've created a sparsebundle just as suggested at http://www.readynas.com/?p=253; however, Time Machine fails to recognize the mounted image. The sparseimage is stored on an external drive, and I already executed:

```
defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1
```

I have also verified that the naming format of the sparsebundle is: MachineName_.sparsebundle. I'm running the latest version of Snow Leopard (10.6.7).

Comment: It's unsupported by Apple and Snow Leopard didn't exist when that tutorial was written. Why do you expect it to still work after a major upgrade of the OS?

Answer (score 2):

Time Machine backups are a nightmare on NAS, however this is what I did with a NetGear Stora:

In Finder -> Go -> Connect to server.

enter your NAS address including username and password, like this:

```
smb://username:password@192.168.0.1/ *or whatever your volume's IP is.*
```

then select to mount the volume of where you want to keep your sparse bundle image.

Now open the disk utility, and create a sparse bundle with the following settings:

- Name: Backup (or whatever)
- Size: 300GB (or whatever)
- Format: Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
- Encryption: none
- Partition: No partition map
- Image Format: sparse bundle disk image
- Save As: yourcomputername.sparsebundle (e.g.: Toms-MacBook-Pro.sparsebundle)

After you've done all that copy it to your backup volume and open Time Machine's preferences

Click on Select Disk and choose the volume that you want to backup to.

======

A couple of suggestions:

1. Follow this screencast that i made to auto mount your volume on start up http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vhcmEd0Y8o
2. Do not upgrade to OSX Lion when it comes out, since at least for my Netgear's Stora the Time Machine did not work and i ended up buying a Time Capsule, check first on the ReadyNAS forums.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the name of the bundle must be `MachineName_MACAddress.sparsebundle`, not `MachineName_.sparsebundle`.

Comment: That used to be the case, but now (at a guess, since Snow Leopard) `MachineName.sparsebundle` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Sparsebundle should be called `[Machine name].sparsebundle`. No trailing underscore.